# Executing plsql code every few minutes in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, html, sql, plsql, oracle-apex

Hi I'm currently designing an application that needs to save people longitude and latitude but I'm having trouble figuring out how to refresh the longitude and latitude every few minutes as well as updating the database and writing the persons new latitude and longitude into my database table.

Edit:

I created a procedure as follows:

```
Create or replace procedure Ins_Location 
    (P_IMU_ID IN Number,
    P_IMUL_LATITUDE IN NUMBER,
    P_IMUL_LONGITUDE IN NUMBER)
is
begin
    insert into i_mobile_user_locations
        (IMU_ID,
        IMUL_LATITUDE,
        IMUL_LONGITUDE)
        VALUES
            (P_IMU_ID,
            P_IMUL_LATITUDE,
            P_IMUL_LONGITUDE);
end;
```

and then i created a process that would start the job as follows:

```
Begin
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
        job_name        => 'ins_location',
        job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
        job_action      => 'BEGIN Ins_Location(:GLOBAL_ID,:P1_LAT,:P1_LNG); END;',
        start_Date      => systimestamp,
        repeat_interval => 'freq = minutely; interval = 5',
        enabled         => true,
        comments        => 'My Location insert'
    );
end;
```

But every time i try to execute the process it gives me this error:
ORA-27452: "BEGIN Ins_Location(:GLOBAL_ID,:P1_LAT,:P1_LNG); END;" is an invalid name for a database object.

Comment: If you have job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE' then you don't need the BEGIN END. Change job_type to 'PLSQL_BLOCK'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on version 20.2 of apex, you can use the feature "Automations" for this. It is then implementation of `DBMS_SCHEDULER` within apex, which is very easy to use and has many out of the box features.

Comment: Yes i am using 20.2 so ill try to go figure out how it works and get back to you thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do something *periodically*, then use `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package - it is designed for such a purpose. It will - in your case - call a stored procedure which contains PL/SQL code you mentioned.

Comment: thanks i'll have to go read up on that and see if i can make it work